# ¿Qué comando SQL puedo usar para trabajar con tres tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo tres tablas: *empleados*, *retardos* y *faltas*.

La estructura y datos de ejemplo para la tabla *empleados* son los siguientes:

| id | no_empleado | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | Juan |
| 02 | 1104 | Luis |
| 03 | 1120 | María |
| 04 | 1121 | José |
| 05 | 1134 | Meli |

La estructura y datos de ejemplo para la tabla *retardos* son los siguientes:

| id | no_empleado | fecha_retardo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | 02/08/21 |
| 02 | 1120 | 02/08/21 |
| 03 | 1120 | 04/08/21 |

La estructura y datos de ejemplo para la tabla *faltas* son los siguientes:

| id | no_empleado | fecha_falta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | 01/08/21 |
| 02 | 1104 | 03/08/21 |
| 03 | 1104 | 04/08/21 |
| 04 | 1104 | 05/08/21 |

Lo que busco obtener es algo así:

| no_empleado | nombre | fecha_retardo | fecha_falta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | Juan | 02/08/21 | 01/08/21 |
| 1104 | Luis |  | 03/08/21, 04/08/21 05/08/21 |
| 1120 | María | 02/08/21, 04/08/21 |  |

No sé con qué consulta SQL se pueda obtener un resultado como el que propongo. Sé que debe ser posible, pero no sé cómo (la única parte con la que tengo mis dudas es con la parte en la que las fechas se concatenan en una misma fila). Cualquier respuesta que me acerque a ese resultado se agradecería bastante. No sé si sea relevante, pero estoy trabajando con PHP. De igual forma lo único que busco en esta pregunta es un comando SQL, pero se agradecería cualquier dato extra.

¡Saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Esto es sencillo usando JOINs y GROUP_CONCAT().

Comment: @LuisCazares, he intentado esto:                                                          
SELECT e.no_empleado, e.nombre, r.fecha_retardo FROM empleados e 
RIGHT JOIN retardos r ON e.no_empleado = r.no_empleado 
UNION ALL SELECT e.no_empleado, e.nombre, f.fecha_falta 
FROM empleados e 
RIGHT JOIN faltas f ON e.no_empleado = f.no_empleado

Answer (score 0):

Al final llegué a la respuesta. No sé si sea la solución más óptima, pero de momento resolvió mi problema. La consulta es:

```
(SELECT e.no_empleado, e.nombre, r.fecha_retardo, GROUP_CONCAT(f.fecha_falta) AS 'faltas'
 FROM empleados e
          RIGHT JOIN retardos r ON e.no_empleado = r.no_empleado
          LEFT JOIN faltas f ON e.no_empleado = f.no_empleado
 GROUP BY e.no_empleado)
UNION
(SELECT e.no_empleado, e.nombre, r.fecha_retardo, GROUP_CONCAT(f.fecha_falta) AS 'faltas'
 FROM empleados e
          RIGHT JOIN faltas f ON e.no_empleado = f.no_empleado
          LEFT JOIN retardos r ON e.no_empleado = r.no_empleado
 GROUP BY e.no_empleado)
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que lo que necesitas es algo por el estilo.

```
SELECT e.no_empleado,
        r.retardos,
        f.faltas
FROM empleados e
LEFT JOIN (SELECT r.no_empleado,
                  GROUP_CONCAT( r.fecha_retardo) AS 'retardos'
          FROM retardos r
          GROUP BY r.no_empleado) r ON e.no_empleado = r.no_empleado 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT r.no_empleado,
                  GROUP_CONCAT( f.fecha_falta) AS 'faltas'
          FROM faltas f
          GROUP BY f.no_empleado) f ON e.no_empleado = f.no_empleado;
```

Comment: Intenté este comando, pero me marca un error con la columna *r.retardos*; me dice que es desconocida en el field *list*.

Comment: Intenta de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

También puedes apoyarte de la sentencia [`with`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), básicamente te ayuda a tener una referencia a una tabla para usarla justo después:

```
WITH retardos_faltas_full_outer_join AS
         (SELECT no_empleado, fecha_falta, fecha_retardo
          FROM faltas
                   LEFT JOIN retardos USING (no_empleado)
          UNION
          SELECT no_empleado, fecha_falta, fecha_retardo
          FROM faltas
                   RIGHT JOIN retardos USING (no_empleado))

SELECT no_empleado, nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(fecha_retardo) retardos, GROUP_CONCAT(fecha_falta) faltas
FROM retardos_faltas_full_outer_join
         JOIN empleados USING (no_empleado)
GROUP BY (no_empleado);
```

Donde `retardos_faltas_full_outer_join` se ve así:

| no_empleado | fecha_falta | fecha_retardo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-02 |
| 1104 | 2021-08-03 | NULL |
| 1104 | 2021-08-04 | NULL |
| 1104 | 2021-08-05 | NULL |
| 1120 | NULL | 2021-08-02 |
| 1120 | NULL | 2021-08-04 |

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas antes que nada identificar las claves foráneas en las tablas retardos y faltas, estas claves foráneas son las que identifican el registro con el registro empleados, yo logro identificar el campo `no_empleado` en las tablas faltas y retardo, ahora solo bastaría hacer una consulta mediante `JOINS` para obtener la información.

Para tu caso creo que con :

```sql
SELECT e.no_empleado, r.fecha_retardo, f.fecha_falta FROM empleados e
RIGHT JOIN retardos r ON e.no_empleado=r.no_empleado
LEFT JOIN faltas f ON e.no_empleado=f.no_empleado
```

debería ser suficiente.

Comment: No creo que esta sea la respuesta que busca el usuario, fijate que en el campo fecha_alta el concatena varias fechas separadas por ','