# ¿Qué comando de SQL se requiere para evitar los valores duplicados trabajando con tres tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo tres tablas: *usuarios*, *faltas* y *pases*

La estructura y datos de ejemplo para la tabla *usuarios* son los siguientes:

| id | no_empleado | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | Juan |
| 02 | 1104 | Luis |
| 03 | 1120 | María |

La estructura y datos de ejemplo para la tabla *faltas* son los siguientes:

| id | no_empleado | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | 01/08/21 |
| 02 | 1104 | 03/08/21 |
| 03 | 1104 | 04/08/21 |
| 04 | 1104 | 05/08/21 |

La estructura y datos de ejemplo para la tabla *pases* son los siguientes:

| id | no_empleado | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1104 | 04/08/21 |
| 02 | 1120 | 01/08/21 |

Estoy generando la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
   (SELECT u.no_empleado, 
           u.nombre, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.fecha)) AS 'pases',
           GROUP_CONCAT(EXTRACT(DAY FROM f.fecha)) AS 'faltas'
      FROM usuarios u 
RIGHT JOIN pases p 
        ON u.no_empleado = p.no_empleado 
 LEFT JOIN faltas f 
        ON u.no_empleado = f.no_empleado 
  GROUP BY u.no_empleado)

UNION

   (SELECT u.no_empleado,
           u.nombre, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.fecha)) AS 'pases',
           GROUP_CONCAT(EXTRACT(DAY FROM f.fecha)) AS 'faltas' 
      FROM usuarios u 
RIGHT JOIN faltas f 
        ON u.no_empleado = f.no_empleado 
 LEFT JOIN pases p 
        ON u.no_empleado = p.no_empleado 
  GROUP BY u.no_empleado)
```

Y se me despliega un resultado como el siguiente:

| no_empleado | nombre | pases | faltas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1120 | María | 1 | null |
| 1104 | Luis | 4,4,4 | 3,4,5 |
| 1100 | Juan | null | 1 |

Lo que busco obtener es algo así:

| no_empleado | nombre | pases | faltas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1120 | María | 1 | null |
| 1104 | Luis | 4 | 3,4,5 |
| 1100 | Juan | null | 1 |

No entiendo porqué con el usuario Luis se despliega el único día que tiene en la columna *pases* tres veces (la misma cantidad de diferentes días que tiene en la columna *faltas*). Agradecería muchísimo su apoyo y de antemano, gracias.

Comment: Esto parece una extensión de tu última pregunta. En esa pregunta di una solución que evita este problema.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué comando SQL puedo usar para trabajar con tres tablas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/480602/qu%c3%a9-comando-sql-puedo-usar-para-trabajar-con-tres-tablas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa DISTINCT en cada GROUP_CONCAT para solo mostrar valores distintos:

`GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT expr)`

En tu ejemplo:

```
   (SELECT u.no_empleado, 
           u.nombre, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.fecha)) AS 'pases',               
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM f.fecha)) AS 'faltas' 
      FROM usuarios u 
RIGHT JOIN pases p 
        ON u.no_empleado = p.no_empleado 
 LEFT JOIN faltas f 
        ON u.no_empleado = f.no_empleado 
  GROUP BY u.no_empleado)
UNION
   (SELECT u.no_empleado, 
           u.nombre, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.fecha)) AS 'pases',
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM f.fecha)) AS 'faltas' 
      FROM usuarios u 
RIGHT JOIN faltas f 
        ON u.no_empleado = f.no_empleado 
 LEFT JOIN pases p 
        ON u.no_empleado = p.no_empleado 
  GROUP BY u.no_empleado)`
```

Documentacion:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Exactamente lo que buscaba. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero que esta query pueda de ser ayuda:

```
SELECT 
usu.no_empleado,
usu.nombre,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(DAY(pas.fecha)) separator ', ') as pases,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(DAY(fal.fecha)) separator ', ') as faltas
FROM usuarios AS usu
LEFT JOIN faltas AS fal
ON usu.no_empleado = fal.no_empleado
LEFT JOIN pases AS pas
ON usu.no_empleado = pas.no_empleado
GROUP BY usu.no_empleado
ORDER BY usu.no_empleado DESC
```

dejo el link dónde hice las pruebas: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0b3f44/3